# How do I force g++ on Linux to update the thread pointer (for TLS) when a coroutine switches threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-local-storage

I'm using a custom implementation of coroutines in C++ (compiler g++, on ARM). The coroutines might migrate from one thread to another by calling a move_to_thread function (or other ways, but this will let me make my point). I'm oversimplifying, but it's kind of like this:

```
__thread int x = 0;

void f() {
    x = 5;
    // do some more work on current thread (thread 1, say)
    move_to_thread(2);
    // do more work, now on thread 2
    int y = x; // with optimization, I'm getting the wrong x
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the work done before and after calling move_to_thread uses thread-local variables (using `__thread`). When compiling with optimization, the code running on thread 2 still accesses thread 1's thread-local variables instead of its own. It's because an access to a thread-local variable does the following:

1. Look up the TLS thread pointer for the current thread
2. Add x's TLS offset to the thread pointer
3. Use the memory at this address as x

However, with optimization enabled, (1) and maybe (2) are being optimized away for the second access, since the compiler assumes a function that begins running on a particular thread will stay on that thread. This assumption is not true for my code.

How can I get the compiler to look at the correct thread-local storage both before and after the call to move_to_thread, without doing away with optimizations completely?

Comment: The compiler is already looking at the correct tls, since it doesnt know anything about your user defined threads. As such, your user defined threads need to come with user defined thread local storage.

Comment: My user-defined things aren't threads. Thread-local storage is meant to be thread-local. So, when a coroutine is running on thread 1 and accesses thread-local storage, it should get thread 1's storage. When it's running on thread 2 and accesses TLS, it should get thread 2's storage. I don't want coroutine-local storage.

Comment: Why do you want coroutines _and_ threads? A coroutine should not care what thread it's on, thus you should not use TLS at all for it.

Comment: That is a good point. However, the question still stands. Is there a way to reliably access thread-local storage in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

What happens if you try declaring your variable as follows:

```
__thread int volatile x = 0;
```

That should prevent the compiler from caching the value (though I'm not sure how volatile interacts with __thread).

Comment: Also, more suggestions. You could expand -O2 to concrete optimization flags, and binary search until you find the one that causes the bug. You can then turn off the offending flag without turning off the rest of the optimizations.

Another option is to pick a different compiler. Do gcc and clang both produce the same error on ARM with optimizations turned on?